# Querying attribute values with LINQ XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am new to querying XML files in C#. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance..

I have this XML file:

```
<Point>
      <Statement>
        <Type />
        <FullCondtion />
        <ExpressionList />
      </Statement>
      <TestList>
        <Test>
          <Inputs>
            <Variable Name="u1_count" Value="0" />
            <Variable Name="u1_flag" Value="2" />
            <Variable Name="ON" Value="1" />
            <Variable Name="OFF" Value="0" />
            <Variable Name="u1_ch" Value="0" />
            <Variable Name="u1_index" Value="3" />
          </Inputs>
          <Outputs>
            <Variable Name="u1_count" Value="0" />
            <Variable Name="u1_flag" Value="0" />
            <Variable Name="ON" Value="1" />
            <Variable Name="OFF" Value="0" />
            <Variable Name="u1_ch" Value="0" />
            <Variable Name="u1_index" Value="0" />
          </Outputs>
        </Test>
        <Test>
          <Inputs>
            <Variable Name="u1_count" Value="0" />
            <Variable Name="u1_flag" Value="2" />
            <Variable Name="ON" Value="1" />
            <Variable Name="OFF" Value="0" />
            <Variable Name="u1_ch" Value="0" />
            <Variable Name="u1_index" Value="3" />
          </Inputs>
          <Outputs>
            <Variable Name="u1_count" Value="0" />
            <Variable Name="u1_flag" Value="0" />
            <Variable Name="ON" Value="1" />
            <Variable Name="OFF" Value="0" />
            <Variable Name="u1_ch" Value="0" />
            <Variable Name="u1_index" Value="0" />
          </Outputs>
        </Test>
      </TestList>
      <TestList>
        <Test>
          <Inputs>
            <Variable Name="u1_count" Value="0" />
            <Variable Name="u1_flag" Value="2" />
            <Variable Name="ON" Value="1" />
            <Variable Name="OFF" Value="0" />
            <Variable Name="u1_ch" Value="0" />
            <Variable Name="u1_index" Value="3" />
          </Inputs>
          <Outputs>
            <Variable Name="u1_count" Value="0" />
            <Variable Name="u1_flag" Value="0" />
            <Variable Name="ON" Value="1" />
            <Variable Name="OFF" Value="0" />
            <Variable Name="u1_ch" Value="0" />
            <Variable Name="u1_index" Value="0" />
          </Outputs>
        </Test>
        <Test>
          <Inputs>
            <Variable Name="u1_count" Value="0" />
            <Variable Name="u1_flag" Value="2" />
            <Variable Name="ON" Value="1" />
            <Variable Name="OFF" Value="0" />
            <Variable Name="u1_ch" Value="0" />
            <Variable Name="u1_index" Value="3" />
          </Inputs>
          <Outputs>
            <Variable Name="u1_count" Value="0" />
            <Variable Name="u1_flag" Value="0" />
            <Variable Name="ON" Value="1" />
            <Variable Name="OFF" Value="0" />
            <Variable Name="u1_ch" Value="0" />
            <Variable Name="u1_index" Value="0" />
          </Outputs>
        </Test>
      </TestList>
    </Point>
  </Pattern>
</CodeAnalyzerResults>
```

I need to write the variables from input and output with their values in a table like this:

**Inputs**

u1_count 0 0 0 0

u1_flag  2 2 2 2

...

u1_index 3 3 3 3

and the same is done for the outputs.. How do I get the input and output values for each variable and write them in a row?

I read this article: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dhananjaycoder/reading-xml-file-through-linq-a-few-tips/ but I still can't think of a way to do it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ to XML (Sytem.Xml.Linq assembly)

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("xml uri");

IEnumerable<string> inputs = 
                        from input in doc.Descendants("Inputs")
                        from el in input.Descendants("Variable")
                        let nameAtt = el.Attribute("Name")
                        let valueAtt = el.Attribute("Value")
                        where nameAtt != null && valueAtt != null
                        group valueAtt.Value by nameAtt.Value into grp
                        let values = string.Join(" ", grp.ToArray())
                        select string.Format("{0} {1}", grp.Key, values);
```

And the same way for `outputs`.

[Edit] grouping by att Value
[Edit] navigating to "Variables" node

Comment: Thanks. But when I tried using it in my code, two errors occured: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IGrouping<string,string>' to 'string[]' and The best overloaded method match for 'string.Join(string, string[])' has some invalid arguments.. Why is that? BTW, I will be writing these on an excel file using a foreach loop.. thanks in advance..

Comment: I was able to use the code by adding '.ToArray' so it became 'let values = string.Join(" ", grp.ToArray())' but then it 'inputs' return "Enumeration yielded no results".. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry I missed something, when navigating to "Inputs" we must go down to the "Variable" elements. I edited the answer and I also added your fix about the `.ToArray` missing. This time I tested it :-P

Comment: Thanks! It worked. :) Now I'm having trouble writing the name and values separately in an Excel file.

Comment: Are you forced to use excel? Can you use CSV ? it would be easier to use CSV. You can for example "join" your values and name using a semicolon ";" and you will have directly a CSV formatted line from your query: for values `string.Join(";",grp.ToArray())` and for the `select` clause `string.Format("{0};{1}",grp.Key, values)`. This way you will have lines like this: **u1_count;0;0;0;0** that you can directly write to a CSV file.